# Global form validation in React-Admin

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-admin

In my React-Admin app, I'm using global form validation.

It mostly works as intended. Following the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html#global-validation), I give the SimpleForm *validate* prop a function that returns an object with errors indexed by field.

But for one of the fields, I need to make a simple api call to check whether the value being entered already exists in the db. If so, I simply want to show a form field error so the user knows to enter a different, unique, name.

Has anyone encountered this use case and gotten it to work?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
const validateNameUnique = (enteredName) => {
  axios(
    withAuth({url: `${API_URL}/names/${enteredName}`})
  ).then(({ data }) => {
    if (data.length > 0) { return true; }});
  return false;
};

const validateItemCreation = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  if (!values.name) {
    errors.name = 'Class Name is required';
  }
  if (values.name) {
    if (validateNameUnique(values.name)) {
      errors.name = ‘name already used’;
    }
  }
  ...
  return errors;
};

const ItemCreate = () => {
  return (
      <Create>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateItemCreation}>
          <TextInput source="name" />
          // other form fields ...
        </SimpleForm>
      </Create>
    </>
  );
};
```

The api endpoint gets called as expected when the user enters a name value, but when it finds a duplicate name in the db, the error does not appear on the form.

This may be some kind of callback issue, though I thought the *then* in the axios call would take care of that.

I searched github for any example of an api call in a react-admin SimpleForm validation function and have not found anything thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your `validateNameUnique` function always returns `false`, try this:

```
const validateNameUnique = async (enteredName) => {
  const data = await axios(withAuth({url: `${API_URL}/names/${enteredName}`})) 
  return (data?.length > 0)   
}

const validateItemCreation = async (values) => {
  const errors = {}

  if (values.name) {
    if (await validateNameUnique(values.name)) {
      errors.name = ‘name already used’
    }
  } else {
    errors.name = 'Class Name is required' 
  }
  ...
  return errors
}
```

[P.S. The validate function can return a promise for asynchronous validation.](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SimpleForm.html#validate)

Comment: For some reason the answer that someone else posted, which was the same as this one, disappeared. No idea why. A bot maybe? Suspended account? No clue.

Comment: The guidance you found in the docs is interesting. It makes it seem like if you want to do asynchronous validation you need to do server-side validation, which then requires a custom save function. In this case, asynchronous validation turned out to be simpler than that. A slight gap in the docs, imo.