# How to make use of DataProvider for server side async validation in React-Admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

*This question is in reference to the React-Admin framework and how to implement a common feature using the methods recommended by the authors. Not about how to request data from an API using pure React.*

Using the code at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html#async-validation as an  example:

```js
const validateUserCreation = async (values) => {
    const errors = {};

    // removed other checks that were here...

    const isEmailUnique = await checkEmailIsUnique(values.email);
    if (!isEmailUnique) {
        // Return a message directly
        errors.email = 'Email already used';
    }
    return errors
};

export const UserCreate = () => (
    <Create>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateUserCreation}>
            <TextInput label="First Name" source="firstName" />
            <TextInput label="Email" source="email" />
            <TextInput label="Age" source="age" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);
```

How would you write the `checkEmailIsUnique` function to query the API from the `UserCreate` component while making use of the [dataProvider](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html) instance hooks instead of writing our own fetch statements as recommended by the authors?

I have a similar scenario where I need to validate uniqueness of the value of a field before creating or updating the record. Can you help me?

====Update===

I wrote a component like:

```
import { TextInput, useDataProvider } from "react-admin";

const ERRORTEXT = "Name is not unique";

interface PartnerNameInputProps {
  source: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

/**
 *
 * `PartnerNameInput` is used to validate if the entered value is available.
 * @example
 * <PartnerNameInput source='name' />
 *
 * In case of an invalid name, you can customize the error message using
 * `errortext` prop.
 */
const PartnerNameInput = ({
  source,
  ...props
}: PartnerNameInputProps): JSX.Element => {
  if (!source || !source.trim()) {
    throw new Error(`'source' must be a non-empty string`);
  }

  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
  const { validate = [], errortext = ERRORTEXT, ...rest } = props;

  async function validateNameUnique(name: string) {
    if (!name) {
      return undefined;
    }

    let isvalid = true;
    try {
      const { data } = await dataProvider.getList("partners", {
        filter: { name },
        pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 10 },
        sort: { field: "id", order: "DESC" },
      });
      isvalid = data.length === 0;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    return isvalid ? undefined : errorobj;
  }

  const errorobj = { message: errortext };

  validate.push(validateNameUnique);

  return <TextInput source={source} validate={validate} {...rest} />;
};

export default PartnerNameInput;
```

But this one doesn't solve for update action, only for the create action. Still looking for a better solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75562987/3368818) and couldn’t figure out how to resolve it using my data provider, so instead I used axios within my react-admin app.

Therefore, this does not exactly answer your question.

But just in case this approach is helpful, the equivalent for you would be something like this:

```
const checkEmailIsUnique = async (enteredEmail) => {
  const data = await axios(withAuth({url:`${API_URL}/emails/${enteredEmail}`})) 
  return (data?.length > 0)   
}

const validateUserCreation = async (values) => {
  const errors = {}

  if (values.email) {
    if (await checkEmailIsUnique(values.email)) {
      errors.email = ‘email already used’
    }
  } else {
    errors.email = 'Email is required' 
  }
  ...
  return errors
}

…
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @woodchuck, but this what I am trying to avoid. 
There are concerns like Authentication that are already solved by the DataProvider and AuthProvider and I would like to not duplicate the efforts and use the framework as intended.

Comment: Definitely. There should be (and may be) a way built into the react-admin framework to do this. I’ve seen it done in older react-admin versions. The Data Provider calls now mostly use hooks, which I haven’t figured out how to get working in this context. Hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on my former version, I wrote a component to validate uniqueness of the values within a given resource/collection.

Some assumptions were made for my scenario, most obvious ones: every record has an `id` field and the DataProvider is firebase.

This one works for both Create and Update!

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { TextInput, useDataProvider, useRecordContext } from "react-admin";

const ERRORTEXT = "Value is not unique";

export interface Filter {
  collectionQuery: (
    c: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference
  ) => firebase.firestore.Query;
}

export interface UniqueValueInputProps {
  source: string;
  resource: string;
  validate?: any[] | any;
  errortext?: string;
  [key: string]: any;
}

interface BuildUniqueValueFilterParams {
  fieldPath: string | firebase.firestore.FieldPath;
  value: any;
  recordId?: any;
}

export function buildUniqueValueFilter({
  fieldPath,
  value,
  recordId,
}: BuildUniqueValueFilterParams): Filter {
  return {
    collectionQuery: (collection) =>
      collection
        .where(fieldPath, "==", value)
        .where("id", "!=", recordId ?? ""),
  };
}

/**
 *
 * `UniqueValueInput` UniqueValueInput is a custom input component used in
 * React Admin applications for validating if the entered value is unique.
 * It performs validation by checking if the entered value exists in a specified
 * resource, excluding the current record (if any) being edited.
 * @example
 * <UniqueValueInput source='name' resource='users' />
 *
 * In case of an invalid value, you can customize the error message using the
 * `errortext` prop.
 * @example
 * <UniqueValueInput source='name' resource='users'
 *     errortext='This name is already taken' />
 *
 * An optional array of validation functions can be passed to the `validate` prop.
 * If provided, these functions will be called after the uniqueness check.
 * Each validation function should return undefined if the validation passes,
 * or an object with a message property if it fails.
 * @example
 * <UniqueValueInput source='name' resource='users'
 *     validate={[validateLenght]} />
 */
const UniqueValueInput = ({
  source,
  resource,
  ...props
}: UniqueValueInputProps): JSX.Element => {
  if (!source?.trim()) {
    throw new Error("'source' must be a non-empty string");
  }
  if (!resource?.trim()) {
    throw new Error("'resource' must be a non-empty string");
  }

  const { validate = [], errortext = ERRORTEXT, ...rest } = props;
  const errorobj = { message: errortext };
  const record = useRecordContext();
  const recordId = record?.id;
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();

  async function validateUnique(value: string) {
    if (!value) {
      console.log("skip remote validation for empty value");
      return undefined;
    }

    const { data } = await dataProvider.getList(resource, {
      filter: buildUniqueValueFilter({ fieldPath: source, value, recordId }),
      pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 1 },
      sort: { field: "id", order: "DESC" },
    });
    return data.length === 0 ? undefined : errorobj;
  }
  validate.push(validateUnique);

  return <TextInput source={source} validate={validate} {...rest} />;
};

export default UniqueValueInput;
```

Used as:

```
export const UserCreate = (props: any) => (
  <Create {...props} validate={validate}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <UniqueValueInput
        source="name"
        resource="users"
        validate={[required()]}
      />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```